# How to use "between" for percentages

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order

I have a question regarding the below pie chart, can I say the following sentence regarding the least practiced activities by girls ? :

*"Listening to music, gymnastics, netball and computer games are between 10 and 16 per cent."*

Can I also say it in the other way around like this ? :

*"Computer games, netball, gymnastics and listening to music are between 16 and 10 per cent."*

Here is the pie chart:

[image]

Comment: [What research have you done?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Did you consult grammar books, search actual English sentences, etc.? Please don't simply ask whether sentences are correct or not. (That's not what this site is for.)

Comment: Wow, this looks familiar. has this question been on here before? Those wedge graphs...

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I did search and look for other samples but I couldn't find an example similar to mine.

Comment: @superkytoz That information belongs in your question (along with where you actually searched), not in a comment. Click the link in my previous comment for advice about how to ask a good question here.